# Crash by executing strstr() inside kernel module

Tags: c, string, linux-kernel, filepath, strstr

I am trying to detect opening folder in a specific location (myPath). I am using strstr() but I see that my system is always crashed([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ly7.png)) after executing this function. If I remove the check (if(ret)), it works as normal
Here is my code:

```
struct task_struct *task_list;
struct fdtable *        fdt = NULL;
unsigned int process_count = 0;
struct path files_path;
char *access_mode;
char *cwd;
int res;
char *myPath = "/home/anh/src/";
char *buf = (char *)kmalloc(GFP_KERNEL,100*sizeof(char));
char * ret;
for_each_process(task_list) {
        fdt = files_fdtable(task_list->files);
        int i=0;
        while(fdt->fd[i] != NULL) { 
            files_path = fdt->fd[i]->f_path;
            cwd = d_path(&files_path,buf,100*sizeof(char));
            if(cwd){//Check if cwd != NULL
                ret = strstr(cwd, myPath);//check seeked file path and myPath
                if(ret) 
                {
                    printk(KERN_INFO "Open file with fd %d  cwd: %s", i,cwd);
                }   
            }    
            i++;
        }
        process_count++;    
    }
```

Could someone review and support me to solve this problem?, why the strstr() cannot be used in a Linux kernel module or is there other ways to verify that a string is in inside a string?

Best regards,
Anh

Comment: are both strings needle and haystack 0 terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plausible explanation is that an error occurs, so `cwd` is not a valid pointer. `strstr` is called on this invalid pointer and crashes. Without `if(ret)`, the `strstr` call is optimized away so there's no crash.

Functions in the Linux kernel typically return an error code on error. The [documentation of `d_path`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/filesystems/API-d-path.html) specifically states that this is the case.

> Returns a pointer into the buffer or an error code if the path was too long.

`if (cwd)` checks that `cwd` is non-null. If `cwd` contains an error code, it's non-null. So `if (cwd)` is not a useful check. The correct [error check](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking/convention-returns.html) for functions that return a pointer is `IS_ERR()`.

```
            cwd = d_path(&files_path,buf,100*sizeof(char));
            if (IS_ERR(cwd)) {
                    printk(KERN_WARN "At i=%d: d_path -> %ld", i, PTR_ERR(cwd));
            } else {
                    ret = strstr(cwd, myPath);
```

Comment: Your explanation is great. cwd has error -> running strstr() is wrong -> Crash. Thank you so much